# split space separated numeric string into a list in Python3

Tags: python, list, integer

Split space separated **Numerical String** into a **List** containing **Numbers**.

I want this:-

`A = '5 2 12 4 29'`

to be this in **single line of code**

`B = [5,2,12,4,29]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`.split()` method returns a list of splitted strings. So you can iterate over it and convert it to a integer

```
A = '5 2 12 4 29'
B = [int(l) for l in A.split()]
```

```
['5', '2', '12', '4', '29']
```

`.split()` method will return something like this. But you want them in integers. So you can follow the above method

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the lambda function as following:

```py
A = '5 2 12 4 29'
B = list(map(lambda x: int(x), a.split()))
print(B)
```

where split() returns a list of strings
and then map function iterates over each string where lambda function converts each string to Integer.

Comment: Ah thanks Mr. Subhash but a simple `int` will do that without using Anonymous function

Comment: Yes sir. Just providing you the options and possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in python3 this style:

```
A = '5 2 12 4 29'
B = A.split(" ")
```

In this case, the split method, with the quotes is used to separate with spaces, as the A has number with spaces, then the quotes to separate would be split(" ")

```
print(B)
# ['5', '2', '12', '4', '29']
```

Comment: Simply ```.split()``` will do

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Bro But I need them in integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using a list comprehension:

```py
A  = '5 2 12 4 29'
B = [int(x) for x in A.split()]
print(B)  # [5, 2, 12, 4, 29]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split( )` to convert the string to a list of individual characters. `['5', '2', '12', '4', '29']`

Since you want integers and not characters, you can use `map()` to convert those individual characters to integers.

```
A = '5 2 12 4 29'
B = list(map(int,A.split()))
print(B)
```

```
[5, 2, 12, 4, 29]
```